# Segmentation fault while access non null struct member-

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, bit-fields

I getting segmentation fault , while compare member of struct with 0.
The confusing part is that the comparison do occur a few times followed by a crush.

please help.
code :

```
Dword addup(void)
{
  Symbol *curr=NULL;
  Dword ans=0;
  plast->next=NULL;

  if( (phead==NULL) || (plast==NULL) )/*checks that the global pointer to the head & tail is not null.*/
      return 0;

  curr=phead;

  printf("point 1 in addup()********\n");

  for( ; curr!=NULL ; curr=curr->next )
  {

      if(curr!=NULL)
      {

          if(  ((curr->feature.oper)==0)  &&  ((curr->feature.ext)==0)  )/*crash here !*/
          {
              puts("point 2AA in addup()********");

              curr->adess=+IC;
              ans++;
          }
          puts("point 2B in addup()********");
      }

      if((curr->next)==NULL)
          break;
  }


  if(  (curr!=NULL) && (plast!=NULL) )
  {
      if(curr==plast)/*meaning all the list been searched.*/
          return ans;
  }


  return (-1); }
```

And the Symbol :

```
typedef struct snode  {
    char label[MAXLABEL];

    Dword adess;

    struct
    {
        unsigned int ext:1;
        unsigned int oper:1;
    }feature;

    struct snode *next;
}Symbol;
```

Thanks to everyone that helps !.

**first edit-
phead is a pointer to the head of the list.
plast is a pointer to the last node(Symbol) of the list.
initialized in other function.
plast->next is always null.(This is in the start of the function - because i want to be sure).

**second edit-
The create function -

```
void csymbl(Dword addess, char *name, Dword ext, Dword ope ){

tempnode.adess=addess;/*tempnode is a global Symbol,that been used to insert new nodes.*/

strcpy(tempnode.label,name);

tempnode.feature.ext=ext;

tempnode.feature.oper=ope;

tempnode.next=NULL;}
```

And the function, that connect it to the list:

```
void addsymbol(Symbol a){

if(phead==NULL)/*if phead point to NULL - meaning this is the first symbol been entered & up now the linked list was empty. */
{
    phead=&a;
    plast=phead;
}
else if(plast==phead)/*If plast point to phead,than there is only one symbol in the list(up to now).*/
{
    plast=&a;
    phead->next=plast;
    plast->next=NULL;
}
else
{
    plast->next=&a;
    plast=plast->next;
    plast->next=NULL;
}}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be NULL to be invalid.

Comment: What is `plast`? What is `phead`? How and where are they initialized? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: How can I check this ?. sorry.

Comment: Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There is not enough information in your question, so we only can guess. All what we can say now is the `curr` pointer is invalid when the crash occurs.

Comment: Oh and since you have a linked list, are you sure the last node in the list have a `NULL` `next` pointer? Remember that if you use `malloc` to allocate memory for the nodes, then it doesn't initialize the memory, so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Just because a pointer is non-NULL, doesn't make it a valid pointer.  You need to show how these symbols are being allocated.  More than likely, you have a symbol whose label exceeds MAXLABEL, and has corrupted the following fields, including next.  Try printing the pointer before the crash point to see if it looks like a series of ASCII.

Comment: always good to check pointer before dereferencing it e.g. `plast->next=NULL;` after that you do `if (plast != NULL)`

Comment: You need to show how you build the list. BTW `curr->adess=+IC;` is that supposed to be `curr->adess+=IC;`

Comment: Please read and understand the 4th comment and edit your question.

Comment: @Michael Walz,
I read it a few times, but for really do this I need to understand the problem(no ?). Im new in C & If I post a question here as last resort.anyway I find the problem. Thanks alot!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `addsymbol` function have a ***very*** serious problem, that will lead to ***undefined behavior***:

```
void addsymbol(Symbol a){
    if(phead==NULL)/*if phead point to NULL - meaning this is the first symbol been entered & up now the linked list was empty. */
    {
        phead=&a;
        plast=phead;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the above code, if `phead` is `NULL` you make it point to the ***local*** variable `a`.

Local variables are called local because they are local inside the function they are defined in, once a function returns the local variables cease to exist. A local variables *lifetime* is only for the scope where it was defined. Arguments are no different from other local variables.

If you store a pointer to such a local variable, then the pointer will become invalid and when you use the pointer you will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You don't initialize `next` for the first element

```
void addsymbol(Symbol a){

    if(phead==NULL)/*if phead point to NULL - meaning this is the first symbol been entered & up now the linked list was empty. */
    {
        phead=&a;
        plast=phead;

        // unless set it can have any value
        plast->next = NULL;
    }

....
}
```

Further you should pass `a` as a pointer like this:

```
void addsymbol(Symbol* a){

    if(phead==NULL)/*if phead point to NULL - meaning this is the first symbol been entered & up now the linked list was empty. */
    {
        phead=a; // Note this changed - no & operator
```

As already mentioned in comments there is a problem here as well:

```
Dword addup(void)
{
  Symbol *curr=NULL;
  Dword ans=0;
  // plast->next=NULL; Don't do it here.... plast may be NULL

  if( (phead==NULL) || (plast==NULL) )/*checks that the global pointer to the head & tail is not null.*/
      return 0;

  plast->next=NULL; // If you really want that code, do it here
```

Finally I wonder if you really want this:

```
          curr->adess=+IC;
```

or this

```
          curr->adess+=IC;
```